# Why are single-speed bikes with disc brakes hard to find?

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, single-speed, hydraulic-disc-brake, hybrid-bike

I've been looking around for bikes (decent frame & components), and find that hybrids do have disc brakes (hydraulic), but are never single-speed. While single-speed bikes typically have [linear-pull brakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_brake#V-brakes).

Why is that? Anything in the mechanics that would make the two incompatible?

(In my case, I'd only want a disc brake on the front — for commuting.)

Comment: Not a big enough market.  People with single speeds most often want "retro" parts, no brakes at all, or as light of a bike as possible. Disc brakes don't really fit any of those descriptions. Although I've thought about building a fixie with disc brakes, on the front at least.  Seems like it would be a very nice bike to own.

Comment: Check out the On-One Pompetamine. Love mine :)

Comment: This might be worth looking at if you are looking to do a conversion of your current single speed. http://www.cxmagazine.com/trp-hylex-hydraulic-disc-brake-lever-singlespeed-cyclocross

Comment: chainreactioncycles.com sells two singlespeed bikes with disc brakes under their own brand name Vitus.
http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/Models.aspx?ModelID=80998

Comment: @user1049697, how's the quality? Never heard of them

Comment: chainreactioncycles.com is claiming to be the largest cycling store in the world, and they are huge and the default go-to store in Europe atleast. I think most Vitus bikes are generally seen to be decent for the price, but I have no idea about the quality of that particular model. It is cheap, but made of hi-ten steel which has a bit of an unfortunate reputation.

Comment: I think Vitus have something to do with Sean Kelly. I was just on a cycling holiday and rode one for a week. Carbon with a 105 groupset, and not a bad ride at all.

Comment: In addition to using an eccentric bottom bracket, you can build up a rear wheel with [White Industries Eccentric ENO hub](http://whiteind.com/rearhubs/singlespeedhubs.html). And to go with that, they have a Disc Eccentric Mount - which can be used to adapt the rear brake to match the rear hub. I'm a happy user of the Eccentric ENO hub - it's easy to set up and use. I've not used the Disc Eccentric Mount - I use V-brakes in the rear.

Comment: Check out the Trek Rig, been riding it whole winter

Comment: @andr, pretty cool, but the front chainring looks a little small — so not really for speed/commuting, but more for steep ascends?

Comment: @Baumr yes you are right, it went with the ratio of 32/18 and I immediately changed it to 36/14 -- much better for speed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Usually, singles need to have horizontal dropouts so you can take the chain slack by adjusting the rear axle position.

That means that any brake that is attached to the frame will "go out of position" when you adjust the rear axle position. That is, by the way, the reason why some horizontal dropouts are not quite horizontal, but diagonal: to be near-perpendicular to the seat stays where rim brakes are attached, so that wheel movement is "tangential" to the brakes.

Unfortunately, with regular disc brakes, this adjustment would totally misalign the brake pads relative to the disk, if the adjustment is possible at all.

Although there are some bikes with grooves for the disk caliper, where you can "slide" the caliper into, it's usually not worth the trouble, because chain slack has to be corrected very often, and caliper setup is relatively laborious.

Also, it would be possible to take the slack with an eccentric bottom bracket, but that is even more esoteric.

Next to that, some single-speeds will come with a flip-flop hub. A flip-flop hub and a disc brake doesn't go well together.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This subtle detail has put the Surly Troll out of my dreamlist...

Comment: There [are bikes](http://spotbrand.com/bikes/product-page/ajax/) that use a [sliding dropout](http://www.paragonmachineworks.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?search=action&category=BC06) or [rocker dropout](http://www.paragonmachineworks.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?search=action&category=BE06) with the disc brake mounts on the sliding part of the dropout. With those, adjusting the tension via the dropout doesn't require messing with the disc brake, since it moves with the adjusting part of the dropout. I haven't yet seen this on cheap or midrange bikes, only expensive or custom so far.

Comment: IF they really wanted to build a fixie with both, front and rear disk brakes, it could be accomplished by having a disk-ready fork and a frame with vertical dropouts and an excentric bottom bracket housing to adjust chain slack. (Agreed it doesn't fit the tipical wants and needs of the fixie rider)

Comment: @heltonbiker: I believe the early model Surly Karate Monkey required loosing the rear disc brake in order to remove the rear wheel! Illustrates the difficulty of SS and disc brakes. However, their new models are disc-only, with track ends for the rear wheel.

Comment: But this issue affects the rear. Who cares about rear brakes.  If a bike was to have only one brake, you'd put it on the front wheel, not the rear, and if it was to have only one disc brake, it would go in the front. In other words, this answer doesn't explain why there aren't single-speed bikes that have a disc brake in the front. (Either just that brake, or that brake in combination with some other kind of brake in the rear, like a hub brake.)

Comment: @Kaz I guess for manufacturer it's way easier to get a PAIR of OEM brakes (discs, calipers, lever), than just a single one. Maybe in the future more manufacturers take advantage of the "front-only-brake-single-speed-bike", but I'm afraid this won't happen for now.

Comment: It might be difficult for the cyclist to get just a front brake at the retail level, but I would think not for a manufacturer who orders thousands of them from a supplier.

Comment: @freiheit such dropouts can be found on Trek Rigs. I guess they fit the "midrange" class

Comment: In many jurisdictions, it's illegal to sell bikes with only a single brake (and rightly so in my opinion).  A fixed gear plus a front brake would get the job done, but if you have a single speed, it's advisable to have both front and rear brakes in the even that you have a cable break, or have some other kind of brake failure.  Even on my fixie I have both front and back because in an emergency situation you don't have time to get your feet into the position for skid braking, not to mention the increased stopping distance if you have to brake with your legs.

Comment: You can use a Ghostring (or simply a tensioner) to solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

It's a cost and market thing. Disc brakes are generally a bit more spendy and require different frames and forks. There are some single speed bikes with discs, especially in the CX world. For your application, consider getting a CX fork that is set up for disk to replace the fork on a single-speed. Note that you will need to replace the wheel too.